# cannot achieve r/w lock on std::map among boost::thread s?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to achieve a r/w lock on a std::map which is shared among multiple threads. First I wrapped std::map and have taken boost::shared_mutex as a class member and wrapped insert/erase/[] operations for thread safety.

I used boost::shared_lock and boost::unique_lock  for r/w synchronization.

I can think of another design where a reader/writer thread can be created and that will exclusively operate on std::map but i thought of a way where i lock/unlock the read or write functions of the std::map. the thing is I am not achieving synchronization.

what am i missing here? do i have to change the design? if yes...can you explain why this design won't work?

here is a r/w lock implementation https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a96d27cb0a3e60c

another boost::mutex implementation is https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/717c26ee1917760a

for reference:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>

std::string gen_random(const int len) {
    char gen_s[100];
    static const char charset[] =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        gen_s[i] = charset[rand() % (sizeof(charset) - 1)];
    }

    gen_s[len] = 0;
    std::string s = gen_s;
    return s;
}
const int ITERS = 100;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class ThreadSafeMap
{

private:
    std::map<T1, T2> _map;
    boost::shared_mutex _lockShared;
    //boost::mutex _lock;
  public:
    ThreadSafeMap();

    bool insert(std::pair<T1, T2> kv);
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator find(T1 k);
    bool erase(T1 k);
    T2 at(int index);
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator end();
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator begin();
    T2& operator[](const T1& k);
    //void operator=(T2 v);
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::ThreadSafeMap()
{
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::insert(std::pair<T1, T2> kv)
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _wrLock(this->_lockShared);
    _map.insert(kv);
    return true;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::find(T1 k)
{

    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _rdLock(this->_lockShared);
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator toReturn = _map.find(k);
    return toReturn;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::erase(T1 data)
{

    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _wrLock(this->_lockShared);
    _map.erase(data);
    return true;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::at(int index)
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _rdLock(this->_lockShared); 
    T2 toReturn = _map.at(index);
    return toReturn;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::end()
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _rdLock(this->_lockShared);
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator toReturn = _map.end();
    return toReturn;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::begin()
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _rdLock(this->_lockShared);
    typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator toReturn = _map.begin();
    return toReturn;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2& ThreadSafeMap<T1, T2>::operator[](const T1& k)
{

    boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _wrLock(this->_lockShared);
    T2& toReturn =  _map[k];
    return toReturn;
}


ThreadSafeMap<std::string,std::string> mapp;

void writer(int threadNo)
{
    while(true)
    {   
        std::string key = gen_random(10);
        std::string value = gen_random(10);
        std::cout << threadNo << " putting " << key << ":" << value << std::endl; 
        mapp[key] = value;
        usleep(100);
    }

}

void reader(int threadNo)
{

    while(true)
    {
        //std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it =  mapp.begin();
        std::string str;
        if(mapp.begin() != mapp.end())
        {
            str = mapp.begin()->first;
            std::cout << threadNo << " retrieved " << mapp.begin()->first << ":" << mapp.begin()->second << std::endl;
            mapp.erase(str);
            std::cout << threadNo << " erased " << str << std::endl;

        }
        //std::string str1 = it->first;
        //mapp.erase(it->first);
        //std::cout << threadNo << " erased " << it->first << std::endl;
        usleep(100);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n = 10; 
    std::vector<boost::thread> allThreadVector;
    while(n--)
    {
        boost::thread t1 = boost::thread(&reader, 10-n);
        boost::thread t2 = boost::thread(&writer,10-n);
        allThreadVector.push_back(std::move(t1));
        allThreadVector.push_back(std::move(t2));
    }
    for (boost::thread &th : allThreadVector)
    {
        // If thread Object is Joinable then Join that thread.
        if (th.joinable())
        {
            std::cout << "joined : " << th.get_id();
            th.join();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

both of these ways generate data races.

this is one of the data race output:

```
1 putting nWlrBbmQBh:CDarzOwKkY

1 retrieved nWlrBbmQBh:CDarzOwKkY1 putting HIDdqSCDXr:JmOWFrxsjy

2 retrieved nWlrBbmQBh:CDarzOwKkY

2 erased nWlrBbmQBh

21 retrieved  putting BldbEFSArC:BynEcdyGgx

==================

WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=23638)

  Read of size 8 at 0x7b1800000050 by thread T1:

    #0 fwrite ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:1048 (libtsan.so.0+0x31a18)

    #1 std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const*, long) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:458 (libstdc++.so.6+0x10ccc3)

    #2 void std::__ostream_write<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream_insert.h:50 (libstdc++.so.6+0x10ccc3)

    #3 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream_insert.h:101 (libstdc++.so.6+0x10ccc3)

    #4 void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> >::operator()<void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, void (*&)(int), boost::_bi::list0&, int) /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:259 (a+0x413a2b)

    #5 boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > >::operator()() /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1294 (a+0x4136ab)

    #6 boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::run() /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:116 (a+0x4132e2)

    #7 thread_proxy <null> (libboost_thread.so.1.66.0+0x124fc)


  Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b1800000050 by thread T2:

    #0 memcpy ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:737 (libtsan.so.0+0x308f5)

    #1 std::char_traits<char>::copy(char*, char const*, unsigned long) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/char_traits.h:350 (libstdc++.so.6+0x11ced1)

    #2 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_S_copy(char*, char const*, unsigned long) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:340 (libstdc++.so.6+0x11ced1)

    #3 std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:272 (libstdc++.so.6+0x11ced1)

    #4 void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> >::operator()<void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, void (*&)(int), boost::_bi::list0&, int) /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:259 (a+0x413a2b)

    #5 boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > >::operator()() /usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1294 (a+0x4136ab)

    #6 boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(int), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<int> > > >::run() /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:116 (a+0x4132e2)

    #7 thread_proxy <null> (libboost_thread.so.1.66.0+0x124fc)


  Thread T1 (tid=23640, running) created by main thread at:

    #0 pthread_create ../../.././libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:915 (libtsan.so.0+0x2af6b)

    #1 boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept() <null> (libboost_thread.so.1.66.0+0x11879)

    #2 boost::thread::thread<void (*)(int), int>(void (*)(int), int, boost::disable_if<boost::thread_detail::is_convertible<void (*&)(int), boost::thread_attributes>, boost::thread::dummy*>::type) /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:401 (a+0x40c163)

    #3 main /tmp/1550569011.2128205/main.cpp:155 (a+0x40685a)


  Thread T2 (tid=23641, running) created by main thread at:

    #0 pthread_create ../../.././libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_interceptors.cc:915 (libtsan.so.0+0x2af6b)

    #1 boost::thread::start_thread_noexcept() <null> (libboost_thread.so.1.66.0+0x11879)

    #2 boost::thread::thread<void (*)(int), int>(void (*)(int), int, boost::disable_if<boost::thread_detail::is_convertible<void (*&)(int), boost::thread_attributes>, boost::thread::dummy*>::type) /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:401 (a+0x40c163)

    #3 main /tmp/1550569011.2128205/main.cpp:156 (a+0x40687a)


SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /root/orig/gcc-8.2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:458 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const*, long)

==================
```

- i have changed the iterator code suggested by B.J.
- I have included the r/w code for future reference suggested by the comment.

Comment: Code should always be included in the question as text. No external links. They might break in the future and render the question invalid.

Comment: Your read of the data via the iterator is not protected by the mutex. So you are mutating the map under the mutex, but reading from it without any synchronization.

Comment: If you forgo the iterators and return the mapped elements by value (e.g. via at) you should be protected (by my cursory inspection). Otherwise you will need to add explicit read lock/release to lock for reading before getting the iterators and using them, and then release the lock after you are done with the iterator.

Comment: @B.J. are you suggesting that i achieve lock outside of the function defined in ThreadSafeMap class or i bring recursive_mutex in the class and lock in calling code and class as well?

Comment: You are still reading from the map when you are not under the lock; you can't use the iterators without holding the lock. I am suggesting you add a "lockForReading()" and "unlockForReading()" to the ThreadSafeMap, and call the lockForReading() before accessing the iterator and unlockForReading() after you are done with it.

Comment: Alternatively, for the specific thing you are doing here, you could add add a "first()" routine to retrieve the element @ begin(); that would work under the lock, and you would not be accessing the iterator...